# How to solve this initial value problem on $(-\infty, \ +\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've managed to solve the following initial-value problem on the interval $(0, +\infty)$: $$x y^\prime - 2y = 4x^3 y^{1/2} $$ with $y = 0$ when $x = 1$. The unique solution is $y = (x^3 - x)^2$.

How to solve this problem on the interval $(-\infty, \ +\infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the substitution

$$ y = z^2 \implies y' = 2zz'$$

Now, work out the problem

Comment: Mhenni Benghorbal, the substitution you suggested changes the given ODE to $xz^\prime - z = 2x^3$, which we can write as $z^\prime - \frac{1}{x} z = 2x^2$. Now the function $P(x) = -1/x$ fails to be continuous at $x=0$. So how to proceed from here on in?

Comment: Now use Integrating Factor. The original problem has the same issue if you divide by $x$.

Comment: Mhenni Benghorbal, thanks, but I would also like to know if we're able to solve this problem with the help of the existence-uniqueness theorme for the first-order linear ODE's.

Answer (score 1):

The solution found in post is not a unique solution satisfying the condition $y(1)=0$. The constant function $y=0$ is also a solution to the problem. The basic existence-uniqueness theorem does not work for that problem because there is $y^{1/2}$ term on the RHS of the equation which is not Lipschitz (or differentiable) with respect to $y$ at the point $(1, 0)$. However, there is another  theorem (Peano's existence theorem) which is only about the existence of (at least) a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the scaling $x \to \alpha x$, $y \to \beta y$ we can see that the equation is invariant whenever $\alpha^{1/2} = \beta^{3}$. It means that $y^{1/2}/x^{3}$ is invariant over the above mentioned scaling. It suggests the variable change $u = y/x^{6}$ or/and $y = x^{6} u$. It leads to:
$$
{1 \over 4\sqrt{u} - 6u}\,{{\rm d}u \over {\rm d}x} = {1 \over x}
$$